# Match relationships if a certain parameter exists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've been using neo4j for a while and recently i got stuck with a query that i don't seem to be able to succesfully run.

My goal: I have a type of relationship called `HAS_RELATIONSHIP`. this type of rel sometimes hasa property called `verified`. I want to get a subgraph of those relationships that don't have this property so i can afterwards add the property.

What I have done so far:

```
Match (a)-[r:HAS_RELATIONSHIP]-(b) 
where  r.verified=False 
set r.verified=True
LIMIT 5
return r, a, b
```

the part that is not working is `where r.verified=False` it should be something like `exists(r)=verified` but t doesn't seem to exist this kind of query. I have checked on `OPTIONAL` MATCH, but it seems it is neither the solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NOT` operator together with the predicate function `exists()` for this problem:

```
MATCH (r) WHERE NOT exists(r.verified) RETURN r
```